# Properly highlighting the selected item in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

by simple coding i would like to have highlight selected item on `RecyclerView` like with this code:

in that only first position of `RecyclerView` item is highlighted and `onClick` on my code dont work

```
private int selected_position = 0; //globally in the Adapter class

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);
    holder.mCoverView.setImageResource(holder.mItem.getCover());
    holder.mTitleView.setText(holder.mItem.getTitle());

    ...

    holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(selected_position == position ? Color.GREEN : Color.TRANSPARENT);
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    public final View mView;
    public final ImageView mCoverView;
    public final TextView mTitleView;
    public final TextView mDurationView;
    public MusicContent mItem;
    public FrameLayout itemsRoot;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
        mCoverView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cover);

        ...

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (getAdapterPosition() == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) return;
        notifyItemChanged(selected_position);
        selected_position = getAdapterPosition();
        notifyItemChanged(selected_position);
    }
}
```

RecyclerView item xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/itemsRoot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:minHeight="?attr/listPreferredItemHeight"

    android:background="@drawable/selectable_item"

    android:transitionGroup="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/duration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/inner_padding"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption" />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

and then `selectable_item` xml content

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryLite" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:state_focused="true"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you've posted, your solution works perfectly. I've recreated it myself with a tiny app, and everything does exactly what it should.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int selectedPosition = 0;
    private MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RecyclerView rv = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.itemview, parent, false);
            return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor((position == selectedPosition) ? Color.GREEN : Color.WHITE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return 1000;
        }
    }

    private class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                if (position != -1) {
                    adapter.notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition);
                    selectedPosition = position;
                    adapter.notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

That means that *something else* in your app is causing your code to not work. My best guess is that your adapter's data is changing over time in a way that's causing `selectedPosition` to become out of sync. For example:

- `selectedPosition` is 10
- a new item is inserted into the list at position 0
- the adapter is notified `notifyItemInserted(0)`

At this point, `selectedPosition` is still 10, but the logically "selected" item is at position 11. When your `onClick()` method runs, you'll notify the item at position 10 that it has been changed, but that won't change the background of the item at position 11, so now you'll have two green rows.

Answer (score 1):

I will tell you a simple way to highlight the selected position item in `recyclerView`
this method does not use and any selector property, I will simply change the background of selected item `onclick` and when you click again I will be reset to its initial state.

```
public class ModelItem {
private String name;

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public boolean isClicked = false;
```

}

I am assuming that you know how to inflate a recycler view with items dummy or with actual data, so I will straight directly show you how to set the `listener` and change the background of `LinearLayout or RelativeLayout`.

You can set your listener on any view like `ImageView` or `TextView`

The model class I have created above will play the key role here the boolean value isClicked will initially set the background to normal and we will change its value on click like this,
below code goes inside your `onBindViewHolder()`

```
YOUR_ITEM_ON_WHICH_YOU_WANT_CLICK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ModelClass m = yourList.get(position);
            if (m.isClicked) {
                m.isClicked = false;
                yourList.set(position, m);
            } else {
                m.isClicked = true;
                yourList.set(position, m);
            }
        }
    });

    if (yourList.get(position).isClicked) {
     // If it is clicked   YOUR_LINEAR_OR_RELATIVELAYOUT.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    } else {
    // If clicked again change the color to its original state
        YOUR_LINEAR_OR_RELATIVELAYOUT.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
    }
```

Let me know if it helps you or I will try to post another example.

Comment: Thanks a lot to help me and reply to my post

Comment: @DolDurma If this solution helped you don't forget to like it :) It gonna help others too